# Upload more than one file on FTP

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ftp

i'm new to objective-c and iOS. I'm using SimpleFTPSample to make test app for uploading and downloading files to ftp. I need to upload two files on ftp, but in SimpleFTPSample you could upload only one...  so what do i need add to source code? I guess there must be some loop, but i don't know where...

Here's my code, i add for() but i know that is wrong, but i do not have any ideas. Thanks for any help.

```
success = (url != nil);

NSMutableArray *listFile = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:2];
[listFile addObject:[[[NSBundle mainBundle]resourcePath]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"1.txt"]];

[listFile addObject:[[[NSBundle mainBundle]resourcePath]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"2.txt"]];


for (int i= 0; i <= 1; i++ ) {

    self.filePath = [listFile objectAtIndex:i];

url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"ftp://anonymous@ftp"];


    url = CFBridgingRelease(
                            CFURLCreateCopyAppendingPathComponent(NULL, (__bridge CFURLRef) url, (__bridge CFStringRef) [self.filePath lastPathComponent], false));
    //                           );
    success = (url != nil);


    self.ftpFileStream = [NSInputStream inputStreamWithFileAtPath:_filePath];
    assert(self.ftpFileStream != nil);

    [self.ftpFileStream open];

    self.ftpNetworkStream = CFBridgingRelease(
                                              CFWriteStreamCreateWithFTPURL(NULL, (__bridge CFURLRef) url)
                                              );
    assert(self.ftpNetworkStream != nil);
    self.ftpNetworkStream.delegate = self;


    [self.ftpNetworkStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        [self.ftpNetworkStream open];

    }

}
```

Comment: have you tried your code without the for loop & the file was uploaded ?

Comment: You know how to upload one file and seriously ask how to upload two files? If you know how to bake a cake, do you have to ask how to bake two cakes? Simple do the same twice (or n-times) and you will upload two (or n) files.

Comment: Yes, if i remove the for loop one file succesfully uploaded. And if i try to do the same action twice, with different path - only first file uploaded and it's empty.

Comment: Have you found any solution ? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can do the uploading of multiple files task in other efficient ways.

1) Using [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

and the other option is

2) [ASIHTTPRequest's](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) ASINetworkQueue

NOTE: ASIHTTPRequest is no longer maintained...happy coding:)

Comment: Thanks for answer, but how should i use AFNrtworking to work with FTP, all examples goes with http, should i just replace "http" with "ftp" in url?

Comment: yes with proper ftp url..Same as uploading files off HTTP, except rather than having http:// as the prefix, you have ftp....
//check this http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/ftpurl.html